# Get all the data for x number of seconds from CQL?

Tags: database, cassandra, timestamp, cql

Below is my CQL table -

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (
  id text,
  record_name text,
  record_value blob,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, record_name)
)
```

here id column will have data like this -

```
timestamp.count
```

And here timestamp is in milliseconds but rounded up to nearest seconds. So as an example, data in `id column` will be like this -

```
1386882930000.1
```

And a single row in the above table will be like this -

```
1386882930000.1 | event_name | hello-world
```

Now my question is -

Is it possible to get all the data for last 5 seconds or 10 seconds or 30 seconds by using the id column?

I am running Cassandra 1.2.9

Comment: There are some good ways to timeslice data and query on it in Cassandra. You need to flesh our your model information a little more though to know what is appropriate. What is "id"? What does it represent in relation to the rest data?

Answer (score 0):

Not for the ID column (assuming you're using a random partitioner (which you should). You can query by time, but you'll need to modify your data model to support it.

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (
  source text,
  event_time timestamp,
  record_name text,
  record_value blob,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, event_time, record_name))
```

Note that everything with the same source will be in the same row (so you should have multiple sources), and everything in that row will be ordered by event_time, then record_name. I also used a timestamp type so that I don't get in trouble with lexical ordering, but if you have a date/time format that is compatible with lexical ordering you'll probably be fine.

[CQL3 Reference](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html)